# Adding coordinates in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am doing a project based on logistics services. So I want to add add routes through which a truck goes. How can I add the coordinates of "from" and "to" locations in mongo?

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify GeoJSON data, use an embedded document with:

```
<field>: { type: <GeoJSON type> , coordinates: <coordinates> }
```

For example, to specify a GeoJSON Point:

```
location: {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: [-73.856077, 40.848447]
}
```

If my answer does not meet your requirements, please consult: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/